# List columns contents from sql table

Tags: php, html, sql

I want to list the contents of a 'name' column from an sql table on a HTML/PHP web page. This page currently allows me to create records, but is there a way of listing the records by name only, and displaying them somewhere specific on the HTML page?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? This is a pretty broad question as it stands.

Comment: please post your code here

Comment: I've left it broad because its the principle of the idea I'm looking for. My code will be useless!

Comment: What do you mean by listing the records by name only? Your question is a little hard to understand.

Comment: What do you need actually? The query, or the html/php code ?

Comment: Sorry it's one of those where the idea is simple but perhaps difficult to convey. I want to list the contents of one particular column from the SQL table

Comment: SELECT your_column_name FROM 'your_table_name'. PLease try this query then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments didn't seem to answer 100% to my knowledge so maybe this broad answer might help.

If you want to grab all the names located in a specific SQL table first make sure to connect to your database using

```
mysql_connect('SERVER', 'USER', 'PASSWORD');
mysql_select_db('DATABASENAME');
```

After you have connected you ran run queries to your database as stated. For your example it would be something like this:

```
//Query to get values
$query= mysql_query("SELECT name FROM TABLE_NAME");
//Places all query results into an array "row"
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
//Prints values as though it were HTML
echo $row['name']."<br>";
}
```

Here's an example of getting one name back from the users table and storing it in a variable to use later in the page.

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM Users");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$name = $result['name'];
?>

<div class="greeting">Hello <?php echo $name; ?></div>
```

In a more advanced case you can also store variables in sessions (cookies) so that you can use them throughout your website (including subdomains) without having to re-query the database each time

```
<?php
session_start();
$query = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM Users");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$_SESSION['name'] = $result['name'];
?>
```

Now whenever you want to grab the variable you just got from the query simple do `<?php $_SESSION['name']; ?>` Just make sure that you have `session_start()` at the top of the page (my suggestion is place in a header file and include the header file in all pages)

Make sure your file is a .php file and you place the code about in the proper `<?php ?>` tags

Comment: Thanks you yes it was just the idea behind it. I have completed this function. How could I then control the output in terms of positioning within the web page? Im good at html and css but not sure how to manipulate an SQL output